# Ionic React Modal Controller error "framework delegate is missing"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

I am facing an issue with Ionic Modal Controller, I am using React. 
I have this error :

> framework-delegate-c2e2e1f4.js:11 Uncaught (in promise) Error:
>   **framework delegate is missing**
>       at framework-delegate-c2e2e1f4.js:11
>       at step (tslib.es6.js:99)
>       at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:80)
>       at tslib.es6.js:73
>       at new Promise ()
>       at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js:69)
>       at attachComponent (framework-delegate-c2e2e1f4.js:2)
>       at class_1. (ion-modal-ios.entry.js:295)
>       at step (tslib.es6.js:99)
>       at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:80)
>       at tslib.es6.js:73
>       at new Promise ()
>       at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js:69)
>       at class_1.present (ion-modal-ios.entry.js:280)
>       at core-80bde1aa.js:1462

Here is the code :

```
import React from 'react';
import {modalController} from '@ionic/core';
import {IonContent,  IonPage,IonItem,IonButton,IonLabel,IonTextarea} from '@ionic/react';
import ModalFormationVote from '../components/ModalFormationVote';

class Test extends React.Component<{}> { 
  constructor(props:any) {  
    super(props);
  }
  openVote(id_formation : number){
    console.log(id_formation);
    let mc = modalController.create({
        component:ModalFormationVote, 
        componentProps:{'id_formation':id_formation},
        swipeToClose:true
    }).then(modalC => {
        modalC.present(); 
    });

  }
  render(){  
    return ( 
        <IonPage>      
            <IonContent> 
                  <IonButton color="primary" expand="block" onClick={() => this.openVote(1)}>open Modal</IonButton> 
            </IonContent>  
        </IonPage>
    );
  }
};

export default Test;
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I manage to make it work using the modal component instead of the controller. Still would like to know what I am doing wrong by using the controller...

Comment: Can you provide your way to solve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Seeing the same thing - how did you solve @Fewl ?

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue with `modalController` ?